# Trash folder survives two drive wipes!

Tags: xubuntu, reinstall

Somebody please convince me that I'm not in the Twilight Zone.  I've been using Xubuntu for years (20.04 presently) but yesterday I was in the mood to be bold so I installed Manjaro from USB, choosing the option to completely overwrite my tiny SSD.

Manjaro turned out to be unnecessarily complex and kept crashing, so I quickly returned to Xubuntu using the USB drive I created several months ago for a reinstall. Again I chose to overwrite the entire drive.

While downloading the latest updates I noticed that my trash folder wasn't empty. When opening it I discovered that all the files that had been in it before the two OS switches were still present!

How could this be so? My only theory is that they somehow were stored in the cloud.

Comment: did you backup and restore your home directory at all?

Comment: Is the trash folder in a separate storage device and / or partition, or like rtaft asked, do you have your home folder in a separate storage device / partition?

Comment: I didn't back up and restore the home directory, but a tiny partition may have survived. To be honest I don't clearly remember. That would explain it, though.

Comment: Did you install these operating systems on top of each other without formatting the drive/partition? That could cause a lot of problems. Wipe the disk first so that you don't have remnants of the other operating system causing problems.

Comment: Nmath, the installation procedure for these operating systems clearly stated that all the data on the disk would be wiped.

Comment: I think you misread.  Format the disk before you install the OS.  You can do this using the "Disks" application from the live session.

Comment: Make a GParted Live disk and boot from that. You can format/wipe the whole drive and manage the partitions before doing an install.